# Return from git checkout <sha1> <directory>

Tags: git

I have run the following:

```
git checkout <commit-hash> some_directory
```

on my `master` and wish to return to the clean state that `master` was at before. My initial thought was that

```
git checkout master
```

would do the trick but to no avail, as some of the files appear as "new" on the branch.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it isn't working? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When yo run `git checkout <commit-hash> some_directory` the files appear as added. You can see this with `git status`:

```
$ git status
On branch test
Changes to be committed:
[...]
```

When you are in this status, you must do:

```
git reset
```

to unstage this changes, and:

```
git checkout .
```

to recover what was in your `HEAD`.

`git reset --hard` will do basically the same in one command.

Answer (score 1):

The answer below assumes you do not have new changes that you want to keep mixed with accidental changes from the errant checkout.

Unstage the changes from the checkout with

```
git reset master some_directory
```

or

```
git reset HEAD some_directory
```

Put the files in your work tree back in their previous state with

```
git checkout HEAD some_directory
```

Finally, clean up any files that may have been deleted in master’s most recent commit with

```
git ls-files -z --others some_directory | xargs -0 rm
```

**If you are absolutely sure** you want to go back to master as-is and don’t mind losing any changes that may be present (whether in `some_directory` or elsewhere), skip all of the above and run

```
git reset --hard master
```

Answer (score 0):

!Copy your full dir first, before you start fixing it ;) Especially if for example you have no remote and local repo is the only one you have.

You would need git reset (or git reset --hard).

Other way could be: switch to some whatever branch, delete master
`git branch -D master`
and then recreate it 
`git checkout -b master origin/master`